# Broken pipe when trying to run a local script with local input file on a cluster accessed via remote host using SSH

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

I am trying to run a local script (eg. hostname.sh) on a cluster on a remote machine using SSH but I am getting the following error:

```
> ssh -A _remote ssh -A _cluster 'bash' < hostname.sh
stdout: write: Broken pipe
```

The file hostname.sh simply outputs the host name in this example, but in general can be more complex. The error is likely to be caused by the incorrect use of pipe, since the following works:

```
ssh -A _remote ssh -A _cluster hostname
> _cluster_name
```

I have tried several solutions but all fail as one way or the other they boil down to ssh to _remote and then trying to read hotsname.sh which in this case not available. What works is copying hostname.sh to _remote, SSH to remote and then running:

```
ssh _cluster "bash" < hostname.sh
```

But this means I have to constantly synch hostname.sh between local and remote machines.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may use "cat hostname.sh | ssh _cluster"

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the command that you're running. I tried to reproduce this with `ssh -A localhost ssh -A localhost 'bash' < hello.sh` and it worked as expected. Maybe _remote or _cluster is doing something strange with non-interactive sessions.

Comment: Do you mean something like 'ssh -A remote "cat hostname.sh | ssh _cluster" '? This returns "cat: hostname.sh: No such file or directory".